# elsarticle: Remove "Abstract title"

Tags: abstract, elsarticle

please help me to remove the "Abstract title" without removing the content of the abstract.

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remove first horizontal rule (above abstract)
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remoce second horizonral rule (below keywords)

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{test title}

\author{ Hariha\corref{cor1}*}


\address{820081,Fukuoka, Japan}
%\fntext[myfootnote]{Since 1880.}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{me@lab.jp}

\begin{abstract}
This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
MEMS
%\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
%\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%\linenumbers
\section{The Elsevier article class}

\paragraph{Installation} If the document class \emph{elsarticle} is not available on your computer, you can download and install the system package \emph{texlive-publishers} (Linux) or install the \LaTeX\ package \emph{elsarticle} using the package manager of your \TeX\ installation, which is typically \TeX\ Live or Mik\TeX.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Could u explain in detail, please. Thank you again

Comment: Remove everything you do not want from the `\renewenvironment` of the answer. A minimum solution would be to use the `xpatch` solution an replace `Summary` by nothing.